# Close votes continue to display the name of removed users while comments don't

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, display-names

If you look at this question, [Preincrement faster than postincrement in C++ - true? If yes, why is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020184/preincrement-faster-than-postincrement-in-c-true-if-yes-why-is-it), you can see that Neil Butterworth's name still displays in the close vote section. However, a comment he made on my answer shows as `anon`.  This should be consistent.

Comment: Since [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155901/162704) is now [status-completed] I imagine this won't be the case for future account removals.

Comment: Or it's a bug that needs to be addressed. :)

Comment: That user was deleted a long, long time ago. We're not going to go back through all the past deleted users and change names around. We also don't change user's names to "anon" anymore, but just to the standard "user######" string upon deletion.

Comment: Despite what animuson said (which I'm sure was true at the time), something must have changed, because I no longer see Neil Butterworth's name among the close voters. I instead see user69307: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0vYz.png. Therefore, I'm marking this as [status-completed]. (I've included proof in the form of a screenshot since I've also gone ahead and re-duped the question so it's no longer closed under the old system. Of course, you can still verify in the revision history: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2020184/revisions)

Comment: @CodyGray [Here is the relevant staff answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310779/377214) documenting the feature change. In short, whenever the system encounters a null user in the close votes table, it will automatically craft "user" followed by their former user ID. (This does have some side effects, such as older account deletions where the username wouldn't be changed to that form upon deletion, as well as manual dissociations which this one is - as the "anon" username [is only used on manual dissociations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/290627/377214).)

Comment: See also [this comment thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310711/if-a-user-changed-their-username-before-their-account-is-deleted-questions-they#comment1015188_310711).